# How to create a new column using pivot table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with the column `typecol` that has values `22` and `33`.
Then I use the following code to make a pivot table:

```
var result = df
        .groupBy(col("product_id"))
        .pivot("typecol")
        .agg(count("*"))
        .na.fill(0)
        .withColumnRenamed("22", "A_type")
        .withColumnRenamed("33", "B_type")
```

However, when values `22` or `33` are not present in `df`, the columns `A_type` and `B_type` are not created. How can I create them anyway with the value `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assemble the columns you want to unconditionally pivot along with their final column names in a `Map` and traverse the Map using `foldLeft` to rename and zero-fill accordingly as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "22"),
  (1, "22"),
  (2, "22"),
  (2, "22"),
  (2, "22")
).toDF("id", "type")

val pivotCols = Map("22"->"a_type", "33"->"b_type")

val pivotDF = df.groupBy("id").pivot("type").agg(count($"type")).na.fill(0)

val resultDF = pivotCols.keys.foldLeft( pivotDF )( (df, c) => 
  if ( df.columns contains c ) df.withColumnRenamed(c, pivotCols(c)) else 
    df.withColumn(pivotCols(c), lit(0))
)

resultDF.show
// +---+------+------+
// | id|a_type|b_type|
// +---+------+------+
// |  1|     2|     0|
// |  2|     3|     0|
// +---+------+------+
```